# Group by but selecting the most recent row

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

So I have a table that I'll simplify like this

```
AppId, Popularity, Date
1      50          2014-04-09
1      60          2014-04-08
2      45          2014-04-09
```

I want to get for a bunch of apps at once, their most recent popularity.

I have this query who works locally but takes way to long on production(more than 3 minutes)

```
SELECT popularity,app_id FROM `popularity`
WHERE `app_id` IN (1..1000) 
AND (`date` = (select max(date) from popularity s where s.app_id = app_id)) 
GROUP BY distribution_application_id
```

Is there a way to optimize it ?

Comment: have you created indexex in table?

Comment: use having max(date) after group by

Comment: use ascending index on date column